# Relational Entity with one Model Class

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am facing Problem with Entity Framework with MVC 4 .

Let me put the Table Structure and result which i needed.

[image]

as you can see i have three table and the data structure is

[image]

can anyone suggest me how can i write Model class so that on create country page i have layout like

**select Language  -- Language Dropdownlist Box here
Enter Country name- country text Box here**

Thanks
Ashutosh

Comment: It is not very normal db structure. Country name must be in Country table, but not in Language table. In that case you will not have any problems with Country create page.

Comment: but how. suppose i have 3 language and want to save data in 3 language then. how can i save 3 different data (country name) in country table.

Answer (score 0):

As already said, you have problems with your table structure, and a model will reflect this, not correct it. And while I am at it, German and Chinese are languages, while Germany and China are countries.

Country Names should be in Countries table, while country_languages is a table allowing a many to many relationship and as such should never be seen by your end user.

If you define your model properly with only Countries and Languages, Entity Framework with Code First will generate a correct Countries_Languages table for you.

Don't forget that in some countries, more than one language is spoken, like Switzerland which has 4 official languages....

Comment: if i put countryname in country table then how can i save text language wise ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure to understand your question. It seems to me you have basic relational database skills to get before working with Entity Framework.

Basically, you don't save "text", you DISPLAY text, and you save a pointer/id to which text was selected by the user.